# Calculate an n-order determinant by FindSequenceFunction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, series-expansion, integer-sequence

Calculate an n-order determinant:

$\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\ n & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 \\ n-1 & n & 1 & \cdots & n-3 & n-2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n & 1\end{array}\right|$

The result should be:

$(-1)^{n-1} \frac{n+1}{2} n^{n-1}$

But I can't get this result by `FindSequenceFunction`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[Mod[#2 - #1, n] + 1 &, {n, n}]
detmm[n_] := Det[a[n]]
tab = Table[detmm[k], {k, 1, 20}];
FindSequenceFunction[tab, n]
```

> FindSequenceFunction[{1, -3, 18, -160, 1875, -27216, 470596, -9437184,
> 215233605, -5500000000, 155624547606, -4829554409472,
> 163086595857367, -5952860799406080,
> 233543408203125000, -9799832789158199296,
> 437950726881001816329, -20766159817517617053696,
> 1041273502979112415328410, -55050240000000000000000000}, n]

Is this due to the limitations of `FindSequenceFunction` or some problems in my method? Is there any other way?

Comment: [`This`](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+-3%2C+18%2C+-160%2C+1875%2C+-27216%2C+470596%2C+-9437184&sort=&language=&go=Search) is it, right?

Comment: I didn't know something like this existed. Thanks for that info, @bmf.

Comment: @E.Chan-López you're welcome. It's useful as a resource. I have found examples where `FindSequenceFunction` fails, but there's a known sequence. This example seems to fall in this category

Comment: @bmf  Thanks for sharing! This website has the same function as `FindSequenceFunction`. It's great!

Comment: @lotus2019 you are very welcome. Actually, OEIS is a database and people can submit known sequences. You can also find Mathematica implementation for those sequences. You might want to send an email to the support team of Mathematica with this case. It's been a while since they updated `FindSequenceFunction` and might be helpful for them to have a library of sequences that could be included.

Comment: @lotus2019 there can be some partial progress with `FindFit` in case you are still interested. Not for the formula itself, but rather to approximate somehow the numerical values by a fit.

Comment: @bmf Thank you very much!  I'll read the help files about `FindFit`.

Comment: @lotus2019 you're welcome. Let me know if you need anything :)